# Navigation bar disappear on larger screen after clicked on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, toggle

I have a carousel and a navigation bar. When it display on mobile devices, the navigation bar will be disappear and the hamburger-icon will appear. When you click the hamburger-icon, the navigation bar will toggle. **The problem is:** if I don't click the hamburger-icon, when I shrink or stretch the screen, the navigation bar and hamburger-icon disappear/appear right, **but if on mobile screen I click the hamburger-icon and close it, after that I stretch the screen, the navigation bar will disappear forever on larger screen.** I'm newbie and I really don't know the reason why. Please help me with this. Thank a lots!

```js
var src1 = "./images/icon-close.svg";
var src2 = "./images/icon-close.svg";


$('#mobile-nav-icon').click(
  function() {

    $('.navbar-list').slideToggle(200);
    $('.navbar-list').toggleClass("background");
    $('.navbar-list').toggleClass("selected");

    var src = $('#mobile-nav-icon').attr('src');
    if (src == src1) {
      $('#mobile-nav-icon').attr('src', src2);
    } else {
      $('#mobile-nav-icon').attr('src', src1);
    }
  }
);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.background {
  background-color: white;
}

.section1 {
  position: relative;
}

.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.selected {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}


/* navbar */

.navbar-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 380%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 8%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 40px 0 3%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.navbar-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1.6% 3% 3%;
}

.navbar-link {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#mobile-nav-icon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 6%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-link:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* reponsive */

@media (max-width:540px) {
  #mobile-nav-icon {
    margin-top: 6%;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 300%;
    top: -30px;
    left: -30px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 150px;
  }
  .navbar-link {
    color: black;
  }
  .navbar-item {
    margin-top: 6%;
  }
  .navbar-item:first-child {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7 nopadding section1">

    <!-- carosel -->
    <div class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="image-hero-1">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navigation">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">room</a>
      <div class="navbar-list-button">
        <ul class="navbar-list">
          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a class="navbar-link" href="#">home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a class="navbar-link" href="#">shop</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a class="navbar-link" href="#">about</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a class="navbar-link" href="#">contact</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <img id="mobile-nav-icon" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="icon-hamburger">

      </div>

    </nav>
 

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using .slideToggle() to show or hide the menu, I would use toggleClass('showing')

Then define the .showing class inside a media query as follows:

```
@media (max-width:540px) {
    .navbar-list {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar-list.showing {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Using .slideToggle() to open and then close the menu, means that when you grow the screen again, it will still be closed.

But by using .toggleClass('showing') you are opening the menu, by adding CSS rules that will only take effect if the screen is thinner than 540px. And when you close it, this class will be removed, so display: none from your more general media query will come back into play. When you then grow the screen, neither media query will apply so you will be back to display: block (menu open).

Comment: I still have 1 more question. If I click the hamburger icon, the navigation bar showing with the background white. If i don't click to close it, when I stretch the screen, the nav still appear with the background. How can I make it even when I don't click the close icon, the nav (with the background) still disappear on larger screen? Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question! You could follow a similar approach, by moving your definitions of the 'background' and 'selected' classes into the media query.

Comment: Thanks, it works. If you don't mind, please help me with the last question. As you can see, I have a carousel image and a background white when showing the navigation bar on mobile screen. My problem is I can't manage for the width of the carousel and navigation bar background always equal to each other when shrink or stretch screen.  Please help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: I would be happy to help you, but it's hard to give a good answer that will help you learn, without knowing what your finished design should look like. Do you have a mockup or sketch of it? If you can provide that, I'd be happy to suggest a good solution (perhaps via chat as this thread is getting long and is unrelated to your original question).

Comment: That would be appreciated. Can you give me your email or something so that I can contact you now? I saw your twitter in your bio but it seem I can't message you.

Comment: I've changed my Twitter settings :-)